# How do I get the SYS data from a Contentful content type from a graphql query?

Tags: graphql, graphql-js, contentful, contentful-api

I need the sys.id to be passed into my props via pageContext. How do I grap this? If I add sys{id} anywhere within my graphql query, it breaks.

return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const PageTemplate = path.resolve('./src/templates/Page.jsx')
    resolve(
      graphql(
        
          `{
            allContentfulPage{
              edges {
                node {
                  id
                  slug
                }
              }
            }
          }`

        ).then(result => {

```
    if (result.errors) {
      console.log(result.errors)
      reject(result.errors)
    }

    result.data.allContentfulPage.edges.forEach((edge) => {
      createPage({
        path: edge.node.slug,
        component: PageTemplate,
        context: {
          id: edge.node.id,
          slug: edge.node.slug
        }
      })
    })
    return
```

Comment: Did you figure this one out? When trying to query a field from sys I get error:

Cannot query field \"sys\"

Comment: Yes. If you are using Gatsby, go to http://localhost:8000/___graphql. You can build out our queries there.

Comment: Yes, I know that. Still, that doesn't answer the question. I was never able to query the "sys" fields. Instead, I ended up querying the "internal" field which worked for what I wanted.